# Is there a trick to show detail description of specific command option in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

Is there a trick to show linux command's specific option? Such as I want to know some detail about tar's `-z` option, and I try this: `tar --help | grep '-z'` but shows nothing.

So is it possible just show details about specific command option?

Appreciate first if you can help me.

Comment: This can make the same effect of what i want, by typing `/-z` after `man tar`.Whatever, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifically for the problem of `tar --help | grep '-z'` not working, do this:

```
tar --help | grep -- '-z'
```

Without the `--`, `grep` takes `-z` as an option rather than an argument.

Comment: `tar --help | grep -- " -z"` more useful for auhor

Comment: Yeah, this works exactly. Thanks for your answer. And I would like to know something detail about `--`, how it works?

Comment: You can read about it here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean/11382#11382

Comment: @HariShankar : I've got it, and thanks again. By the way, it also works without quotation mark.